How do I reset a picture-in-picture window position in Google Maps?
After a screen orientation change, Google maps misplaced its "picture-in-picture" window to mostly off screen, and I'm unable to drag it back to a position where it's fully visible.

Changing the screen orientation or enabling / disabling the picture-in-picture view didn't help.
Is there a way to reset / move such a window without reinstalling Google Maps?

As a workaround I would disable the navigation bar and change it to gesture navigation, that maximizes the touchable area of the Google Maps mini-window. Normally if you touch a pip window a blue bar appears at the top where you can move it around. Not sure if this works in your Android version the say way.

I managed to get the picture-in-picture window back by opening a messaging app and bringing up the keyboard. This shifted all content up, and Google Maps window (which was drawn over the keyboard) could be interacted with.
